# How to delete a UITableView Cell with a delete button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have implemented a copy, edit, and delete button on to each cell produced by my UITableView (Each cell is created by user demand). The copy and edit button are coded in the same manner and work just fine. However, every time I press the delete button I get an error "Thread 1: signal SIGBART". Not sure how to fix. Any help would be appreciated.

Some useful information: 
- Each cell is a section, and each section has one row in the tableview
- buttons are connected appropriately in the code for the cellview and are appropriately delegated for use in the table view.

I'm a beginner for swift, so please bear with me. The below code is from my UITableViewController. I attempt to delete the cell from the section index and the object that it is referencing. Then, i attempt to reload the data on the UITable view. However, the moment the delete button is clicked, I just get an error.

```
func hashtagCellDidTapDelete(_ cell: HashtagCell) {
    if tableView.indexPath(for: cell) != nil {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        tableView.deleteSections([(indexPath?.section)!], with: .fade)
        hashtagSource.hashtags.remove(at: (indexPath?.section)!)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the item from the data source and then update the UI.

And use Optional Binding to unwrap the optional `indexPath` to avoid the ugly parentheses, question and exclamation marks.

And never call `reloadData()` after `insert/deleteRows/Sections`.

```
func hashtagCellDidTapDelete(_ cell: HashtagCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        hashtagSource.hashtags.remove(at: indexPath.section)
        tableView.deleteSections([indexPath.section], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! After doing this I still got some errors, but I realized there was some error in the count of my array. Once I got that sorted out, your code fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

we can not delete uitableview cell instead of remove entry from your array which is passed in your datasource method like

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { }
```

or

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {}
```